# Does phantomjs use all of webkit or parts of it?

Tags: webkit, phantomjs

wondering if phantomjs uses all the rendering bits of webkit as well ? other than image capturing usecase running a js script on page can be done on render tree , with the js executed on it and part of the CSS executed , to allow for any CSS selector in the js script. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. PhantomJS is a full browser that supports JavaScript and CSS. The only difference is that it doesn't have a "head" so you need to write scripts to use it.

Comment: Hi Artjom, i was recently reading about webkit components and different stages of rendering a web page. It seems that even after a render tree is constructed webkit relies on several platform dependent modules e.g graphics engine, font renderer etc. Now if primary use case of phantomjs is to let scripts be executed then it may not need all those submodules. Given its ability to take snapshots it still probably needs some of those, but if there is a phantomjs lite without the snapshot taking ability then theoretically it can pack less of webkit.

Comment: That's a good point. You should ask the PhantomJS developers. AFAIK, they don't frequent StackOverflow anymore. Please include this comment in your question.